i purchased a secugen hamster pro 20 fingerprint scanner, it doesnt seem to support LINUX UBUNTU 22. is there a specific driver for it to work
device not compatibe on linux ubuntu 22 and not taking any inputs of fingerprint and also it does not worrk offline. any advice s to how to get it running and is there any driver for the secugen hamster pro20 anyone is aware of or do i need to make some changes to the coding or something.

Ubuntu 22?  So you're using a Ubuntu Core 22 system? as 22.04 has kernel stack defaults, thus you have kernel stack choice (drivers are kernel modules; giving more flexibility of options).  You mention 22, but tagged 22.04 which is the Server product Ubuntu Core 22 is derived from.  The server systems are usually used headless (esp. 22 which has no desktop options; they exist only for 22.04) so there is no need for local fingerprint logins.
